# Default value for object argument

Tags: javascript

I want to create a function with an object as parameter 
The object can have for exemple three keys : **x, y, z** 
All this keys must have default value assignment

*I tried this :*

```
function f({x:x, y:y, z: z} = {x:1,y:2,z:3}) {
  return x + y + z;
}
```

*But I have a problem*

```
f() // return 6 => OK!
f({x: 2, y: 3, z: 4}) // return 9 => OK!
f({x: 2, y:3}) // return NaN (because z === undefined), I expect 8
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

You can assign individual defaults when destructuring objects:

```js
function f({ x = 1, y = 2, z = 3 } = {}) {
  return x + y + z
}

console.log(f())
console.log(f({ x: 2, y: 3, z: 4 }))
console.log(f({ x: 2, y:3 }))
```

[See the docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values), which describes array destructuring, but the same applies to objects.

Answer (score 0):

**What does destructuring mean?** It’s a JavaScript expression that allows us to extract data from arrays, objects, maps and sets into their own variable. It allows us to extract properties from an object or items from an array, multiple at a time.

**Short form:** The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

---

Please have a look at this simple code example:

```js
function yourFunction({
  x = 1,
  y = 2,
  z = 3
} = {}) {
  return x + y + z
}


out.innerHTML+="<br>" + yourFunction()

out.innerHTML+="<br>" + yourFunction({ x: 3, y: 3, z: 4 })

out.innerHTML+="<br>" + yourFunction({ x: 7, y: 1})
```

```html
<p id="out">Results: </p>
```

Have a look at the docs: [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values)

Comment: Please read [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). There is no explanation of what you are doing or why. There are no links to resources that the OP can read up on.

Comment: You say *The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression*, so what part of what you wrote is that expression - show and explain the actual syntax, not a definition of the syntax. A good way to do this is to place comments in the code.